# Update json in logic apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I want to parse through a json and update specific nodes in json result according to the following code snippet written in power shell:

```
    foreach($val in $getresult.elements.values)
              {
                if($val.Name -eq "Config")
                {
                    $val.items.Service=$ServiceValue
                }
                if($val.Name -eq "Analysis")
                {
                    $val.items.ID=$IDValue
                    $val.items.Name=$NameValue
                }
                if($val.Name -eq "Report")
                {
                    $val.items.to=$ToValue
                }
              }
```

The final `$getresult` elements/nodes should be updated with `$ServiceValue`, `$NameValue` and `$ToValue`. How do I achieve it in logic apps?

Answer (score 3):

We recently introduced new workflow functions `@setProperty`, in combination with condition action you will be able to set the properties inside. Or, use `@addProperty` if such name doesn't exist.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language